# simple update query dosn't work for column value decrement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I want to run this query :

```
update table_name set Debt = Debt - 5 where Id = some_value
```

but it decrements the 'Debt' column as twice value of given number in query (hear 10) it also works for '+' operator correctly .

I have no idea where I am wrong.

please help.

Comment: Can you share an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) that demonstrates this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I closed the phpMyAdmin panel tab in my browser and opened the tab again
then problem solved but still don't know the problem's reason. 
It seems it's a phMyAdmin panel bug.